# postgres search in column with escapes

Tags: postgresql, search, grep

Is there a way to do something like a grep for "site" from the following select (so that only "site=*" is returned from thedata)?

```
rr=# select thename,encode(thedata, 'escape') from
management_data.datas limit 2;
       thename            |  thedata                                                                                                                                                                            

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander                   | #
                                                                               +
                                   | #Fri Mar 15 14:58:18 PDT 2014
                                                                               +
                                   | BUs=ALL
                                                                               +
                                   | site=33$36$354$380$357$360$36$353$36$38$39$34$31$355
                                                                               +
Anthony                     | #
                                                                               +
                                  | #Mon Jan 05 13:33:00 PST 2015
                                                                               +
                                  | mem=12000
                                                                               +
                                  | site=50$5$1$50
                                                                               +
                                  |
```

Comment: what is the schema definition for datas table ?

Comment: @DavidChan `     Column     |          Type          |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 thename       | character varying(80)  | not null                                              | extended |              |
 thedata       | bytea                  |                                                       | extended |              |`

Comment: What a ghastly way to store information - you seem to be shoving it into a `bytea` blob. That's going to be no fun at all to query from SQL. (a http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be handy, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Given test data round-tripped successfully:

```
WITH somerow(name, blobofgarble) AS (
    SELECT 
      TEXT 'Alexander', 
      BYTEA E'#\n#Fri Mar 15 14:58:18 PDT 2014\nBUs=ALL\nsite=33$36$354$380$357$360$36$353$36$38$39$34$31$355\n'
) 
SELECT name, encode(blobofgarble, 'escape') FROM somerow;
```

Now, I can't possibly imagine why you'd store this information as `bytea` not a `text` field, but ... well, I guess there must be a reason. I'm going to rely on the simplifying assumption that the data, when escaped, can be treated as fairly sanely formed `text`, since otherwise the whole concept of "lines" is garbage and your question makes no sense.

With that assumption it's possible to use `regexp_split_to_table` to split on newlines, getting somewhat more sanely formed data:

```
WITH (...)
SELECT name, garblepart FROM somerow, regexp_split_to_table(encode(blobofgarble, 'escape'), E'\n') AS garblepart;

   name    |                garblepart               
-----------+------------------------------------------------------
 Alexander | #
 Alexander | #Fri Mar 15 14:58:18 PDT 2014
 Alexander | BUs=ALL
 Alexander | site=33$36$354$380$357$360$36$353$36$38$39$34$31$355
 Alexander | 
(5 rows)
```

(this is an implicit `LATERAL` query, so it'll only work in PostgreSQL 9.3 and above).

Now you can use pretty ordinary operations to find the row of interest and extract the desired part, in this case with some more pattern matching:

```
WITH (...)
SELECT 
  name, substring(garblepart from '=(.*$)')
FROM somerow,
     regexp_split_to_table(encode(blobofgarble, 'escape'), E'\n') AS garblepart
WHERE garblepart LIKE 'site=%';

   name    |                    substring                    
-----------+-------------------------------------------------
 Alexander | 33$36$354$380$357$360$36$353$36$38$39$34$31$355
(1 row)
```

Now *go fix your schema* so that you store your data sanely and don't have to do this.

Comment: You are a god amongst men. This is perfect. You are perfect.